# React: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am running a React application.

When I enter the page through routes(click button or link) page works fine but when I reload the page it crashes. I cannot see where the error is, the console and source show just blank, this is the server message console message.

```
server: Entrypoint index [big] = index.js index.1af9d975ff74be4d27d9.hot-update.js index.c93bf08301ec20c0dc85.js.map index.c93bf08301ec20c0dc85.js.map
server:    533 modules
server: backend debug read session { csrfToken: '0ae87c36d850008df20b58941bf89072', id: 2 }
server: backend debug {"data":{"currentUser":null}} <= undefined
server: backend debug {"data":{"currentUser":null}} <= undefined
server: backend debug read session {}
server: backend error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
server:     at getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
server:     at hoistNonReactStatics (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js:71:38)
server:     at resolveComponent (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@loadable/component/dist/loadable.cjs.js:332:3)
server:     at InnerLoadable.loadSync (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@loadable/component/dist/loadable.cjs.js:189:24)
server:     at new InnerLoadable (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@loadable/component/dist/loadable.cjs.js:138:17)
server:     at processChild (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3048:14)
server:     at resolve (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3013:5)
server:     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3436:22)
server:     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3395:29)
server:     at renderToStaticMarkup (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3969:27)
server:     at process (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@apollo/react-ssr/lib/react-ssr.cjs.js:38:16)
server:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
server: backend debug read session { id: 3 }
server: backend debug loading <= currentUser
server: backend debug loading <= currentUser
server: backend debug loading <= currentUser
server: backend debug {"data":{"currentUser":{"id":3,"username":"canercak@gmail.com","role":"user","isActive":true,"email":"canercak@gmail.com","__typename":"User"}}} <= currentUser
server: backend debug {"data":{"currentUser":{"id":3,"username":"canercak@gmail.com","role":"user","isActive":true,"email":"canercak@gmail.com","__typename":"User"}}} <= currentUser
server: backend debug {"data":{"currentUser":{"id":3,"username":"canercak@gmail.com","role":"user","isActive":true,"email":"canercak@gmail.com","profile":{"firstName":"Caner","lastName":"Çakmak","fullName":"Caner Çakmak","__typename":"UserProfile"},"auth":{"certificate":null,"facebook":{"fbId":null,"displayName":null,"__typename":"FacebookAuth"},"google":{"googleId":"104801577244556473676","displayName":"Caner Çakmak","__typename":"GoogleAuth"},"github":null,"linkedin":null,"__typename":"UserAuth"},"__typename":"User"}}} <= currentUser
server: backend debug read session {}
server: backend error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
server:     at getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
server:     at hoistNonReactStatics (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/dist/hoist-non-react-statics.cjs.js:71:38)
server:     at resolveComponent (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@loadable/component/dist/loadable.cjs.js:332:3)
server:     at InnerLoadable.loadSync (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@loadable/component/dist/loadable.cjs.js:189:24)
server:     at new InnerLoadable (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@loadable/component/dist/loadable.cjs.js:138:17)
server:     at processChild (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3048:14)
server:     at resolve (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3013:5)
server:     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3436:22)
server:     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3395:29)
server:     at renderToStaticMarkup (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3969:27)
server:     at process (/Users/apple/Desktop/dev/bethabit/node_modules/@apollo/react-ssr/lib/react-ssr.cjs.js:38:16)
server:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

this is the code that runs. I tried removing currentuser, addhabit and many other things to just to understand where the error comes from. No results. Everything works fine if I enter the page through a link.

HabitaddView.web.jsx

```
const HabitAddView = ({ addHabit, t, currentUser }) => {
  const renderMetaData = () => (
    <Helmet
      title={`${settings.app.name} - ${t('habit.title')}`}
      meta={[
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: t('habit.meta')
        }
      ]}
    />
  );
  return (
    <PageLayout>
      {renderMetaData()}
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 padTop10">
          <h2>{t(`habit.label.create_new`)}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <HabitForm onSubmit={onSubmit(addHabit)} currentUser={currentUser} />
    </PageLayout>
  );
};
```

HabitForm.web.jsx

```
const HabitForm = ({ values, handleSubmit, setFieldValue, submitting, t  }) => {
  const [habitType, sethabitType] = useState('Fitness Habits');
  const [intervalText, setIntervalText] = useState(t('habit.field.interval'));

  const [habitActions, sethabitActions] = useState([]);
  const [habitFreqs, sethabitFreqs] = useState([]);
  const [habitDurations, sethabitDurations] = useState([]);
  const [habitIntervals, sethabitIntervals] = useState([]);

  const [showInterval, setshowInterval] = useState(true);
  const [showHabitDiv, setshowHabitDiv] = useState(false);

  const [habitActionDisabled, sethabitActionDisabled] = useState(true);
  let calendarComponentRef = React.createRef();
  let calendarWeekends = true;
  let [calendarEvents, setCalendarEvents] = useState([]);

  var timeZones = moment.tz.names();

  const handleHabitTypeChange = (type, value, setFieldValue) => {
    setFieldValue(type, value);
    resetValues();
    Object.values(settings.habits.list).map(object => {
      if (object.habit_type == value) {
        const _habitActions = [];
        Object.values(object.habit_actions).map(object2 => {
          _habitActions.push(object2.title);
        });
        sethabitType(value);
        sethabitActions(_habitActions);
        setshowHabitDiv(false);
        sethabitActionDisabled(false);
      }
    });
  };

  const updateIntervalText = worktype => {
    if (worktype === 5) {
      setIntervalText(t('habit.field.number'));
    } else if (worktype === 6 || worktype === 7) {
      setIntervalText(t('habit.field.proof'));
    } else {
      setIntervalText(t('habit.field.interval'));
    }
  };

  const handleHabitActionChange = (type, value, setFieldValue) => {
    const preparedValue = Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value;
    setFieldValue(type, preparedValue);
    const _habitFreqs = [];
    const _habitDurations = [];
    const _habitIntervals = [];
    resetValues();
    Object.values(settings.habits.list).map(object => {
      if (object.habit_type == habitType) {
        Object.values(object.habit_actions).map(object2 => {
          if (object2.title == preparedValue) {
            Object.values(object2.duration).map(object4 => {
              _habitDurations.push(object4);
            });
            Object.values(object2.interval).map(object5 => {
              _habitIntervals.push(object5);
            });
            sethabitFreqs(_habitFreqs);
            sethabitIntervals(_habitIntervals);
            sethabitDurations(_habitDurations);
            setshowHabitDiv(true);
            setFieldValue('timezone', moment.tz.guess());
            setFieldValue('worktype', object2.worktype);
            setFieldValue('description', object2.description);
            setFieldValue('misc', JSON.stringify(object2.misc));
            updateIntervalText(object2.worktype);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  const handleValueChange = (type, value, setFieldValue) => {
    const preparedValue = value;
    setFieldValue(type, preparedValue);
    let timezone = values.timezone;
    let interval = values.interval;
    let duration = values.duration;
    if (type === 'timezone') {
      timezone = value;
    } else if (type === 'interval') {
      interval = value;
    } else if (type === 'duration') {
      duration = value;
    }
    updateCalendarEvents(values.habit_action, timezone, interval, duration);
  };

  const empty = e => {
    switch (e) {
      case '':
      case 0:
      case '0':
      case null:
      case false:
      case typeof this == 'undefined':
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  };

  const resetValues = () => {
    values.duration = '';
    values.interval = '';
    values.timezone = '';
    updateCalendarEvents(values.habit_action, values.timezone, values.interval, values.duration);
  };

  const updateCalendarEvents = (habit_action, timezone, interval, duration) => {
    setCalendarEvents([]);
    let events = [];
    if (!empty(timezone) && !empty(interval) && !empty(duration)) {
      var dur = JSON.parse(duration);
      var int = JSON.parse(interval);
      var times = dur.count;
      var counter = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        if (i % int.step === 0) {
          counter += 1;
          var obj = {
            title: values.habit_action + ' ' + int.title,
            start: moment
              .tz(values.timezone)
              .add(i + 1, 'days')
              .format(),
            allDay: true
          };
          let addObj = true;
          if (values.worktype === 7 && i === 0) {
            addObj = false;
          }
          if (dur.weekdays === true && (moment(obj.start).isoWeekday() === 6 || moment(obj.start).isoWeekday() === 7)) {
            addObj = false;
          }
          if (
            values.worktype === 7 &&
            counter > 2 &&
            counter < 10 &&
            (habit_action === 'Stay Alcohol Free' || (habit_action === 'Stay Nicotine Free' && dur.count === 28))
          ) {
            obj.start = moment
              .tz(values.timezone)
              .add(i + (counter - 1), 'days')
              .format();
            true;
          }
          if (addObj) {
            events.push(obj);
          }
        }
      }
      if (habit_action === 'Stay Alcohol Free' && dur.count === 28) {
        events.sort(function(a, b) {
          return moment(b.start) - moment(a.start);
        });
        events.shift();
        events.shift();
      }
      setCalendarEvents(events);
    }
  };
  if (settings.habits.list) {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-5">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-body">
              <Form name="habit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field
                  name="habit_type"
                  component={RenderSelect}
                  type="select"
                  label={t('habit.field.habit_type')}
                  value={values.habit_type}
                  onChange={value => handleHabitTypeChange('habit_type', value, setFieldValue)}
                  cols={1}
                >
                  <Option value={0}>--Please Select--</Option>
                  {Object.values(settings.habits.list).map((object, i) => {
                    return (
                      <Option key={i} value={object.habit_type}>
                        {object.habit_type}
                      </Option>
                    );
                  })}
                </Field>
```

habitadd.jsx

```
class HabitAdd extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    currentUser: PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.subscription = null;
    this.state = { options: [] };
  }

  render() {
    if ( this.props.currentUser) {
      return <HabitAddView {...this.props} />;
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(ADD_HABIT, {
    props: ({ ownProps: { history, navigation }, mutate }) => ({
      addHabit: async (
        habit_type,
        habit_action,
        duration,
        interval,
        timezone,
        description,
        worktype,
        misc,
        user_id
      ) => {
        let habitData = await mutate({
          variables: {
            input: {
              habit_type: habit_type,
              habit_action: habit_action,
              duration: duration,
              interval: interval,
              timezone: timezone,
              description: description,
              worktype: worktype,
              misc: misc,
              user_id: user_id
            }
          },
          optimisticResponse: {
            __typename: 'Mutation',
            addHabit: {
              __typename: 'Habit',
              id: null,
              habit_type: habit_type,
              habit_action: habit_action,
              duration: duration,
              interval: interval,
              timezone: timezone,
              description: description,
              worktype: worktype,
              misc: misc,
              user_id: user_id,
              days: [],
              bets: []
            }
          }
        });

        if (history) {
          window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/habit/' + habitData.data.addHabit.id;
        } else if (navigation) {
          return navigation.push('HabitEdit', { id: habitData.data.addHabit.id });
        }
      }
    })
  }),
  graphql(CURRENT_USER_QUERY, {
    props({ data: { error, currentUser } }) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      return { currentUser };
    }
  })
)(HabitAdd);
```

---

Thanks to Ace, I realized my mistake.
Added this code line on habitAdd render method

```
render() {
    if ( this.props.currentUser) {
      return <HabitAddView {...this.props} />;
    } else {
      return <div></div>;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please check `const HabitAddView = ({ addHabit, t, currentUser }) => {` whether your props got currentUser property or not?

Comment: yes they have. HabitAddView.propTypes = {
  addHabit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  currentUser: PropTypes.object,
  t: PropTypes.func
};

Comment: It looks that until some point you don't have `currentUser` yet. If you component relies on the current user, then you should render empty state of the component or not render the component in the parent component. Then, when current user will be loaded, the component will be rendered properly.

Comment: try to add a default value to currentUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the `currentUser`. Consider initializing it. Before routing I am assuming you are setting the value for the `currentUser` or the `currentUser` is being set to a value, but on refresh, the value is reset, though the component will load, the value for `currentUser` isn't available hence the error.

Comment: how do I initialize on refresh? everything works on routing..

Comment: you need to initialize `currentUser` to maybe an empty string. So during the routing flow, the relevant value will be assigned to it. On refresh, the store is reset to the initial state, since you `currentUser` is initial, you would not face this issue.

Comment: thank you, I solved it by rendering an empty div just before the current user loads

Comment: yes, the conditional rendering also fixes the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

VSCode is helpful here. Try running the node app in debug mode with *--inspect* option, with **Pause on Exceptions** option checked.

Alternatively you could look into configuring your app to have longer stack traces, or use something like longjohn [https://www.npmjs.com/package/longjohn] that aids with that.

Answer (score 0):

It happened when inlineRequires are enabled in metro.config.js. Try disabling it and run the build again...

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: true,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  }
};
```